# Why Cassandra does not allow udf in update statements?

Tags: cassandra, cql, udf

I am new to Cassandra. I created a table, and I have inserted some data in it, now I want to select data from it, and in the output, I want some calculated columns.

I created a user defined function `concat`, which concatenates 2 strings and returns the result. Then I noticed that this function shows data correctly when I use it in SELECT statement. but it does not work when I use in UPDATE statement:

That is, this works;

```
select concat(prov,city), year,mnth,acno,amnt from demodb.budgets;
```

but this does not;

```
update demodb.budgets set extra=concat(prov,city) where prov='ON';
```

In addition, the UPDATE also does not work if we simply assign one column's value to another column of same type (without any calculations), as below;

```
update demodb.budgets set extra=city where prov='ON';
```

Also, even a simple arithmetic calculation doesn't work in Update statement;

that is, this too doesn't work;

```
update demodb.budgets set amnt = amnt + 20 where prov='ON';
```

here `amnt` is a simple double type column.

(when I saw this; all I could do is pull my hair hardly and say, I can't work with Cassandra, i don't just want it if it cannot do simple arithmetic)

Can someone please help how can I achieve the desired updates?

Comment: Why would you want to work with Cassandra in the first place? What about your `select`, are you happy with them?

Comment: I am working with Cassandra because company wants to use it and my boss has asked me to learn it.

Comment: I was hoping to get a grasp on the bigger picture...

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic answer to your question is *Read-before-write is a huge anti-pattern in Cassandra*.

The issue of concurrency in a distributed environment is a key point there.

[More info](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_manage_ondisk_c.html).